# how is my deck deck list?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander, deck-building

I'm building a [Teysa Karlov](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=457356) commander deck. I have a couple of win cons in the deck like [revel in riches](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=435271) and [pitiless plunderer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=439738) with Teysa Karlov makes the treasures supper fast. I also have infinite combos with [blasting station](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=51131), [reassembling skeleton](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=447252), and pitiless plunderer with Teysa out it makes infinite damage. there are board wipes and targeted removal as well as a bunch of blood artist type types and tokens. and [helm of the host](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=443105) to make a lot of Teysa's. I'm looking for some improvements and how I did building it.

I also know I want to put in Divine visitation and Bishop of wings to make infinite angles. as well as putting Exquisite Blood with Epicure of blood to continuously damage everyone. and I want to put in Nether Traitor because with him Ashnod's altar and Prismite (i don't have a phyrexian altar or the money for one so that's the compromise I have to make), with thoughts cards make infinite mana into a soul drain or I could get damage with falkenrath noble or tokens with open the graves.

I really want this deck to be really competitive and hope to get some more inspiration out of this question for more cards to add.

The decklist is [here](https://decks.tcgplayer.com/magic/commander/hoppin-onefoot/teysa-karlov-deck-with-just-cards-i-could-find-around/1366725)

TLDR: I'm looking for help with my Teysa Karlov commander deck.

PS. they said I couldn't have more than 8 links sorry about not linking all the cards I thought id do the more important ones that I brought up more than once.

Comment: Seems like kind of opinion based?

Comment: @CollinB I didn't know whether or not it was opinion based I looked on the meta and I couldn't tell whether getting help on a deck lest was considered that. because I found things that said that we could as for help with what the best cards were in a list or slightly broader. I'm not trying to make a discussion I just wanted help with my deck :)

Comment: I'd recommend looking at any of the numerous deck building websites, that provide automatic suggestions first.  Such as this link: https://edhrec.com/commanders/teysa-karlov  Then, play with your deck a bit, find out it's weaknesses, then you'll have the basis for a better question.

Comment: This is less opinion based than it appears to be, because decklists crystallize quite quickly once a format is solved. People agree on what is good, what is not good, which cards are flexible, how to approach certain matchups, and so on. The only problem is, the format is commander, and the best brains in Magic don't usually think about commander (which after all is supposed to be a just-for-fun format).

Comment: Hmmm I feel like I may have misspoke. Less that it's opinion-based, more that it's just a large question. I would also reccomend edhrec.com, but I'll write up an answer later.

Comment: @SkylarCaldwell just noticed it was closed, sorry. Feel free to ask in the chat, however. I would be happy to help you out!

Comment: @collinB I'm not sure as to what chat your referring to, i also looked on edhrec and found out somemore suff. if i have any questions ill be sure to ask

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49/board-and-card-games

Comment: @SkylarCaldwell That is the link to the board games stackexchange chat